# How to avoid Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2

Tags: apex, queueable-apex

I am trying to run a test class which is inserted and updating the same account.

I do have a queaueable class calling from onAfterInsert and onAfterUpdate. Do I have a quick fix for it?

```
public void onAfterUpdate( List<Account> newAccounts, Map<Id, Account> oldAccountMap )
{
    syncData();
    //Here is where I am calling the runIntegrateQueauable
    System.enqueueJob(new runIntegrate(oldAccountMap,newAccounts));
}

public void onAfterInsert( List<Account> newAccounts )
{
    syncData();
    //Here is where I am calling the runIntegrateQueauable
    System.enqueueJob(new runIntegrate(newAccounts));
}
```

ADDING THE TEST METHOD

```
@isTest static void testTrackCompanyRatings_UNASSIGNED_OWNER()
{
    User testUser = setupTestUser( 'Analyst Full', 'standt' );
    User unassignedUser = setupTestUser( 'Analyst Full', 'unassign' );
    
    System.runAs(unassignedUser) {
    }
    
    System.runAs(testUser) {
        System.debug('======'+userinfo.getUserName());
        Common_Config__c config = CommonConfigUtil.getConfig();
        Set<String> accountDealFields = new Set<String>();
        String accountDealFieldQueryStr = '';
        for( String dealField : config.Company_Rating_Fieldnames__c.split(',') )
        {
            accountDealFields.add( dealField.deleteWhitespace() );
            accountDealFieldQueryStr += dealField + ',';
        }
        accountDealFieldQueryStr = accountDealFieldQueryStr.removeEnd( ',' );
        
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'TestAccount';
        a.Website = 'http://www.testwebsite.com';
        a.Company_Quality__c = COMPANY_QUALITY;
        //          a.Deal_Type__c = DEAL_TYPE;
        a.Deal_Imminence__c = DEAL_IMMINENCE;
        a.Deal_Size__c = DEAL_SIZE;
        a.Deal_Notes__c = DEAL_NOTES;
        a.OwnerId = testUser.Id;
        
        Test.startTest();
        
        insert a;
        // a.OwnerId = [select id from User where alias='unassign' limit 1].Id;
        a.Loss_Drop_Reason__c ='Accidental Pickup';
        a.Loss_Drop_Notes__c='Tetsing';
        
            
            update a;//**If I comment this line I am not getting the error**
        Test.stopTest();
    }
    
    List<Company_Rating__c> updatedRatings = Database.query( 'SELECT Id, Current_Rating__c FROM Company_Rating__c' );
    System.assertEquals( 1, updatedRatings.size() );
    
    List<Account> updatedAccounts = Database.query( 'SELECT Id, Company_Quality__c, Deal_Type__c, Deal_Imminence__c, Deal_Size__c, Deal_Notes__c FROM Account' );
    System.assertEquals( 1, updatedAccounts.size() );
    //System.assert( String.isBlank( updatedAccounts[0].Company_Quality__c ) );
    //      System.assert( String.isBlank( updatedAccounts[0].Deal_Type__c ) );
    //System.assert( String.isBlank( updatedAccounts[0].Deal_Imminence__c ) );
    //System.assert( String.isBlank( updatedAccounts[0].Deal_Size__c ) );
    //System.assert( String.isBlank( updatedAccounts[0].Deal_Notes__c ) );
}
```

How can I achieve this?:**Make sure you don't call enqueueJob twice at any point in the same transaction. For example an insert that would call an update and would execute enqueueJob twice.**  I think I am doing the same case. But I don't know how can I prevent it

Comment: @Derek F Could you please guide please

Comment: Asking people directly like that is considered rude. Saying something is "urgent" here is usually counterproductive. The best thing you can do is to provide adequate detail and respond promptly to any questions/feedback from comments.

Comment: Sure Thanks. I will provide more details

Comment: You should include your test class (or perhaps just the test method that's failing). It's not clear how you're getting into a situation where you're running both an insert and an update. It's possible that appropriate usage of `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` could resolve the problem, but we'd need to see your test class to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

While queueable apex can be chained indefinitely in normal operation, tests are different.

When you use `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()`, any asynchronous calls made inside start/stopTest (@future, queueable, schedulable, batchable) are converted into *synchronous* calls that are run immediately after `Test.stopTest()` (otherwise they wouldn't be run as part of the test's transaction).

Queueable apex can be run synchronously without Test.start/stoptest by simply passing a null into the execute method (there's probably *some* use for the information in QueueableContext, but it doesn't really provide much that would affect code). That's not as easy to do when your queueable call is part of a trigger though.

Probably the simplest fix would be to simply move your `Test.startTest()` to be after you insert your test record.

Failing that, you could manage things by including a test-visible boolean in your trigger handler like this...

```
public class MyHandler{
    @testVisible
    private static Boolean runSync = false;

    public void afterInsert(){
        if(MyHandler.runSync){
            MyQueueable.execute(null);
        }else{
            System.enqueueJob(new MyQueueable());
        }
    }
}
```

That would allow you to, say, declare that you just want to run the queueable synchronously for inserting a record. You'd set that flag to true (in your test method) before your test inserts the record, and then set it back to false before updating it.

Using @testVisible does leave a bit of a bad taste in my mouth, but the upside is that you wouldn't have un-coverable lines like you would by using `if(Test.isRunningTest())`

Comment: But it is getting alwaays false

Comment: @NBR The point of using `@testVisible` is that you _can change the value in a unit test_ (even if it's a private variable). It's only false until you change it to true (in your test method).

Comment: It is not changing to true when it is changed from test method
I am not sure why am I getting it false
  AccountTriggerHandler.runSync=true;
  update a;
   AccountTriggerHandler.runSync=false;

Comment: I solved it with if(Test.isRunningTest()).But I would like to know what is the root cause of the issue. Maybe in the future, I can resolve without any assistance and can help someone  who is facing  the same

Comment: @NBR I believe my answer already covers the cause of the issue (it's because of async code being forced to run synchronously)

Comment: I got this same error when flow tried to update the record. Is there anything I can update to avoid this? Is there something I am doing wrong?